# Typescript error when using SearchBar from react-native-elements

Tags: typescript

I'm using `import { SearchBar } from 'react-native-elements';`

It has a `onChangeText` function with the type of `onChangeText: () => any;`

I do `onChangeText={(text: string) => console.log("text", text)}` and it's giving me the ts error:

```
Type '(text: string) => void' is not assignable to type '((text: string) => void) & ((text: string) => void) & (() => any) & (() => any) & (() => any) & ((text: string) => void) & (() => any) & (() => any) & (() => any)'.
  Type '(text: string) => void' is not assignable to type '() => any'
```

Why and what's the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this issue](https://github.com/react-native-elements/react-native-elements/issues/3089), the type definition is broken in the latest version. Until the new version come out, you can do the following to overcome the problem.

**01 way: Downgrade it to 3.4.0**

```
// npm
npm install react-native-elements@3.4.0

// yarn 
yarn add react-native-elements@3.4.0
```

---

**OR**

**02 way: Refer to the base props like the comment suggested in the issue**

```js
import { SearchBar } from 'react-native-elements';
import { SearchBarBaseProps } from 'react-native-elements/dist/searchbar/SearchBar';

// Using SearchBarBaseProps instead of SearchBarDefaultProps & SearchBarAndroidProps & SearchBarIOSProps
const SafeSearchBar = (SearchBar as unknown) as React.FC<SearchBarBaseProps>;

const CustomSearchBar = () => {
    return (
        <SafeSearchBar
            platform="default"
            placeholder="Type Here..."
            onChangeText={(text: string) => console.log("text", text)}
            // value={search}
        />
    );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for finding this issue report. I'll just go with option 3 and ts-ignore these since it's only cosmetic, until the next release.

Answer (score 0):

This has been handled with the v4. See https://github.com/react-native-elements/react-native-elements/issues/3227#issuecomment-999831580